# Did Firebase.js 7.x break compatibility with Typescript 2.6.x?

Tags: typescript, firebase, ionic-framework

We've been using Firebase (just the database) in an Ionic 3.x project without any compilation errors until Firebase pushed out version 7.0.0.
The common Typescript version used with Ionic 3.x projects is 2.6.2.

Is there anything we can do to resolve this knowing that it's not an option to upgrade our Typescript dependency? Or is it a Firebase bug or dropped support (which has not been communicated)?

The way we import the library is standard:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/database';
```

ionic serve output:

```
[app-scripts] [10:36:47]  transpile started ... 
[app-scripts] [10:36:54]  typescript: node_modules/firebase/index.d.ts, line: 4336 
[app-scripts]             ';' expected. 
[app-scripts]     L4335:  gtagName?: string;
[app-scripts]     L4336:  /** Sets custom name for `dataLayer` array used by gtag. */
[app-scripts]     L4337:  dataLayerName?: string;
[app-scripts] [10:36:54]  typescript: node_modules/firebase/index.d.ts, line: 4336 
[app-scripts]             'EventNameString' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here. 
[app-scripts]     L4335:  gtagName?: string;
[app-scripts]     L4336:  /** Sets custom name for `dataLayer` array used by gtag. */
[app-scripts]     L4337:  dataLayerName?: string;
[app-scripts]             'never' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here. 
[app-scripts]     L4335:  gtagName?: string;
[app-scripts] [10:36:54]  typescript: node_modules/firebase/index.d.ts, line: 4336 
[app-scripts] [10:36:54]  typescript: node_modules/firebase/index.d.ts, line: 4336 
[app-scripts]     L4336:  /** Sets custom name for `dataLayer` array used by gtag. */     
[app-scripts]     L4337:  dataLayerName?: string;
[app-scripts]             Cannot find name 'T'. 
[app-scripts]     L4335:  gtagName?: string;
[app-scripts]     L4336:  /** Sets custom name for `dataLayer` array used by gtag. */ 
[app-scripts]     L4337:  dataLayerName?: string;
```

So for the time being we're stuck with firebase 6.6.2.

Comment: I don't see anything related in the release notes: https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js If you think there's a bug in a Firebase JavaScript SDK release, it's probably best to report that on the open-source repo of that SDK: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks. Let's see... https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/2335

Answer (score 3):

Short answer - yes. The nice folks at Firebase shed some light:
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/2335#issuecomment-549606361

> Yes, it did break compatibility with Typescript versions prior to 2.8. It wasn't intentional, but we used a conditional type for analytics that is not recognized by pre-2.8 versions of Typescript. Are you able to upgrade your Typescript version? I was able to npm i typescript@latest in my test Ionic project and run it successfully but I don't know if you have other constraints that prevent you from upgrading.
>
> We are looking into what we might be able to do to fix it for users of earlier Typescript versions but if you are able to safely upgrade Typescript to 2.8+ this may be the quickest way to unblock you for now.